# Https request race scenario

Tags: post, https, network-programming, client

Lets say I have -

1. A HTTPS POST request (R1) with a payload of 500kB.
2. A HTTPS POST request (R2) with a payload of 50KB.

If R1 is fired from the same client machine before R2 (by a small duration say 5ms), is it a guarantee that R1 will reach the server before R2?

Does it depend on the difference of time intervals between firing of requests?

Does it depend on payload?

Comment: There are two different things here: establishing the connection and sending the entire payload over the wire. By *reach the server* which one of the two do you mean?

Comment: I would imagine establishing the connection would take the same time, anyways, I was talking about entire payload over the wire!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If R1 is fired from the same client machine before R2 (by a small duration say 5ms), is it a guarantee that R1 will reach the server before R2?

No, there are no guarantees that the first request will complete before the second one even if it was sent 20ms before it.

> Does it depend on the difference of time intervals between firing of requests?

The difference is of course important. The later you send R2 after R1, the better chances you have R1 to complete before R2.

> Does it depend on payload?

Yes, the payload is another important factor that should be taken into account because this payload will need to go through the wire, which comes with the respective network latency.

So to conclude: you cannot rely on any order. The only way to guarantee that R1 will complete before R2 is to have the client **wait** for R1 to complete **before** sending R2.